# What's the final word on "What X are available" and "List of X" type questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

What is our final decision on questions like these?

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/40606/what-arcade-platform-or-role-playing-games-are-available
- [What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu)

Our [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) is quite clear on the subject:

- > What kind of questions should I not ask here? ...
  >
  > ...
  >
  > You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on **actual problems** that you face
  >
  > ...avoid asking [questions where]...
  >
  > - every answer is **equally valid**: “What’s your favorite ______?”

So, let us set some guidelines. Should we close or lock all of them? Should we add a notice to the old ones like [Stack Overflow do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a *variation* of this which is allowed, namely "Hidden Features of..."

[Should 'hidden features of X' be removed/closed/locked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/should-hidden-features-of-x-be-removed-closed-locked)

The difference as I see it, is these aren't just mindless *lists of stuff*, but pro-tips where experts share specific details about how they do things.

A simple "what is available" or "let's list all things of type X" does not fit this criteria at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Ask Ubuntu is the place for them.

Close and lock them all and add a notice to the old ones ([like they did on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)).

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about this, one of the problems is that these questions often start as valid requests, [like this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49174/is-there-a-source-insight-alternative) where someone asks for an alternative to a program that only runs in Windows.

Knowing where to draw the line is quite tricky.

Comment: An excellent point. We should definitely not close specific, reasonable requests for software recommendations. I suppose you'll often be able to distinguish them by thinking about whether it is a "questions based on actual problems that you face". For example: "I desperately need an alternative to x" is reasonable, "I just want to try some different x" is not. In short: You've got to have a *[problem](http://i.imgur.com/n4u5V.jpg).*

Answer (score -1):

We should allows posts that have a limited scope like "What Platformers are available?" but close or lock the posts with unlimited scope like "What Native Games are available?" .

Comment: "What Platformers are available?" still doesn't conform with the FAQ: "every answer is equally valid".